# How to instruct Hudson to ignore duplicates in Job Queue?

Tags: java, hudson

There is a possibility in Hudson to add one and the same job many times to the queue. I don't understand what is the reason of this and would like to block such a possibility to all users. Is it possible to do? Maybe some plugin may help?

Comment: I don't have that problem, I just tried manually triggering the same job twice (actually something like 15 times) and it didn't go twice in the waiting list. I had only two in the build queue one waiting and one executing. What kind of job is it and what Hudson version are you running? I have version 1.381

Comment: @Peter You're right, it doesn't happen when I trigger builds from web panel. But the duplication problem appears when I trigger them via direct HTTP GET requests...

Answer (score 0):

The idea is the following. If you have a build which is triggered by changes in the VCT (Version Control Tool) it could happen that a build will be triggered multiple times. But in Hudson there is a default [quiet time](http://www.hudson-labs.org/content/quiet-period-feature) (5 sec)

Comment: Right, but why do I need 5 builds triggered by 5 changes in VCT, if they all are waiting in the queue? One build is enough to wrap all those changes. That's how CruiseControl and Apache Continuum work, for example.

Comment: You could decrease the amount of times Hudson polls your source code repository (e.g. once every 10 minutes instead of once a minute). This allows multiple changes occurring within the polling time to be included in one build.

Comment: @Bernand The problems appears when the queue **already** contains my project waiting, and Hudson polls SCM (or is triggered by some other method). In this case I don't want it to add the same job to the queue. There is no reason in it. But it adds..